# How do I change the text inside of a div once the div is hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I simply have this division on a website I am creating that has some text in it

like "example" once I hover over the division I want the text to change into "whatever".

I found this forum but I dont really understand, could someone explain?

[link](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/change-contents-of-div-on-hover/)

Answer (score 2):

Try it with the event listener `mouseover`.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Whatever';
})
```

```html
<div>
  Example
</div>
```

If you want to set the text back to "Example" whenever the mouse pointer moves out of the div, use the event Listener `mouseout`.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Whatever';
});

div.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'Example';
});
```

```html
<div>
  Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using Javascript, simply solution would be:

```css
div {
  background: tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div span {
  display: none;
}

div span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
}

div:hover span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link you shared, they are used Pseudo Element in CSS and there's already have the answer. 
Read this for reference:

[Pseudo Element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

[Pseudo Element : Before](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is to use the css-pseudo-selectors `::before` and `::after`, because those have a content-property. Like so:

```css
.hover-me { background: orangered; }
.hover-me::after { content : "Bleh." }
.hover-me:hover::after{ content : "Blahargh!" }
```

```html
<div class="hover-me"></div>
```

But from a maintenance perspective you want to be consistent with where you put content and where you put styles. ("uh, did I put my text in CSS or HTML this time around?") , and the content you can use is pretty limited (no html), but it can be good to know about at least.